# correspondence between epi and monos

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, monomorphisms, epimorphisms

I want to know if there is a problem with this argument:

Let $C$ be a category and $F$ be a faithful functor  $C^{op}\rightarrow C$, with left adjoint $F^{op}: C\rightarrow C^{op}$
If $f: A\rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism, this means that $g\circ f=h\circ f\Rightarrow g=h$.
Now if I apply $F$ on this, I will get:

$F(g\circ h)=F(h\circ f) \Rightarrow F(g)=F(h)$

this means:

$F(f)\circ F(g)=F(f)\circ F(h)\Rightarrow F(g)=F(h)$

so $F(f)$ is a monomorphism.

Also, let $F(f)$ be a monomorphism, and $F^{op}$ be the left adjoint of $F$ then:
$F(f)\circ F(g)=F(f)\circ F(h)\Rightarrow F(g)=F(h)$

$F^{op} F(g\circ f)=F^{op} F(h\circ f)\Rightarrow g=h$

so $f$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: The statement that $F(f)$ is a monomorphism would be that for any morphisms $\alpha,\beta$, the equality $F(f)\circ\alpha=F(f)\circ\beta$ implies $\alpha=\beta$. Can you see why what you wrote is different?.

Comment: I thought I can write that because $F$ is faithful ...

Comment: What you wrote is ok. It's just that it's different from the definition of monomorphism. Can you see why it is different?

Comment: Sorry but no... I don't see it... Would you please explain more?

Comment: I think for each $\alpha$ there exists some $F(k)$...

Comment: There may be some $\alpha$ which is not the image of any morphism under $F$.

Comment: Oh, that needs $F$ to be full?

Comment: And on what grounds do you assert that $F$ has a left adjoint?

Comment: In addition, even if $F$ is full, it may not be surjective on objects. What you need for $F(f)$ to be a monomorphism is that for all objects $X$ and all morphisms $g,h\colon X\to B$, $F(f)\circ g = F(f)\circ h$ implies $g=h$. So you need there to be an object $C$ such that $F(C)=X$, and you need there to be morphisms $\alpha,\beta$ such that $F(\alpha)=g$ and $F(\beta)=h$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it as an assumption

Comment: To be honest, I wrote this to solve exercise 6 of chapter 4 in book sheaves in geometry and logic, but I didn't mention it because I wanted to solve it myself.... but now I think I can't do it....... there  $C$ is a topos and $F$ is the exponential functor....